# NAudio debug mode crashes out of application when trying to use CoCreateInstance to initialize Avid ASIO Driver

Tags: c#

I have used NAudio for many years with many versions and have seen this problem from the beginning. I do not care about using the Avid driver as it is unusable anyway. I just do not want the app to crash if someone tries to use it. I can block it out but how many other ASIO drivers are out there with the same problem. Try loops in C# do not catch the exception, just bails out of the app every time. Has anyone seen this before? Here is where it crashes in NAudio.Wave.AsioOut:

```
    private void InitFromGuid(Guid asioGuid)
    {
        const uint CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = 1;
        // Start to query the virtual table a index 3 (init method of AsioDriver)
        const int INDEX_VTABLE_FIRST_METHOD = 3;

        // Pointer to the ASIO object
        // USE CoCreateInstance instead of builtin COM-Class instantiation,
        // because the AsioDriver expect to have the ASIOGuid used for both COM Object and COM interface
        // The CoCreateInstance is working only in STAThread mode.
        int hresult = CoCreateInstance(ref asioGuid, IntPtr.Zero, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref asioGuid, out pAsioComObject);
        if ( hresult != 0 )
        {
            throw new COMException("Unable to instantiate ASIO. Check if STAThread is set",hresult);
        }

        // The first pointer at the adress of the ASIO Com Object is a pointer to the
        // C++ Virtual table of the object.
        // Gets a pointer to VTable.
        IntPtr pVtable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pAsioComObject);

        // Instantiate our Virtual table mapping
        asioDriverVTable = new AsioDriverVTable();

        // This loop is going to retrieve the pointer from the C++ VirtualTable
        // and attach an internal delegate in order to call the method on the COM Object.
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos =  typeof (AsioDriverVTable).GetFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = fieldInfos[i];
            // Read the method pointer from the VTable
            IntPtr pPointerToMethodInVTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pVtable, (i + INDEX_VTABLE_FIRST_METHOD) * IntPtr.Size);
            // Instantiate a delegate
            object methodDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pPointerToMethodInVTable, fieldInfo.FieldType);
            // Store the delegate in our C# VTable
            fieldInfo.SetValue(asioDriverVTable, methodDelegate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only error message I get on the output screen is: The program '[3640] WindowsFormsApp1.exe' has exited with code 16 (0x10).

Comment: I stepped into 2.0.1 to see how the NAudio demo was able to get an exception.  It got past CoCreateInstance and all the way to the AsioDriverExt constructor where it failed gracefully at this code in the constructor: if (!driver.Init(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(driver.GetErrorMessage());
            }

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to get a very detailed list of all the audio devices on my desktop and whether or not they function. It was a bit convoluted, but it works. I took the latest revision 2.0.1 demo project and striped out everything not needed except my class which gathers the data on all the devices. The latest revision runs in emulator mode and seems to work fine. I am sure it could be done with earlier revisions as well without emulator mode. The only problem is that since the original demo project is a solution itself, I cannot add it to my solution. Nevertheless, I can run it as a separate process and write the data output to the hard drive. I thought maybe the c++ code was crashing the app because it ran on the same thread as the GUI thread but that is not the case. It all runs on the main thread. I guess it to worked because of the Reflection strategy the demo uses.